# Override a Vendor's module di.xml : add an argument

Tags: magento2, overrides, di.xml

I have in some Vendor's Module di.xml file this entry :

```
<type name="Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Pdf\PdfInformation">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="variables" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">quote</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::USERNAME</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getCustomerName</item>
            </item>
            <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">custom</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::CUSTOMER_STREET</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getBillingStreet</item>
            </item>
            <item name="2" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">billing</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::CUSTOMER_CITY</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getCity</item>
            </item>
            <item name="3" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">custom</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::CUSTOMER_REGION</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getBillingRegion</item>
            </item>
            <item name="4" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">billing</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::CUSTOMER_POSTCODE</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getPostcode</item>
            </item>
            <item name="5" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">custom</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::CUSTOMER_COUNTRY</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getBillingCountryName</item>
            </item>
            <item name="6" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">billing</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::CUSTOMER_TELEPHONE</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getTelephone</item>
            </item>
            <item name="7" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">quote</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::QUOTE_NUMBER</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getIncrementId</item>
            </item>
            <item name="8" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">quote</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::QUOTE_STATUS</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getStatusLabel</item>
            </item>
            <item name="9" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">quote</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::QUOTE_DATE</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getCreatedAt</item>
            </item>
            <item name="10" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">quote</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::QUOTE_EXPIRY_DATE</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getExpiredDate</item>
            </item>
            <item name="11" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">custom</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::SHIPPING_STREET</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getShippingStreet</item>
            </item>
            <item name="12" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">shipping</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::SHIPPING_CITY</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getCity</item>
            </item>
            <item name="13" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">custom</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::SHIPPING_REGION</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getShippingRegion</item>
            </item>
            <item name="14" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">shipping</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::SHIPPING_POSTCODE</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getPostcode</item>
            </item>
            <item name="15" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">custom</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::SHIPPING_COUNTRY</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getShippingCountryName</item>
            </item>
            <item name="16" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">custom</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::SHIPPING_TELEPHONE</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getTelephone</item>
            </item>
            <item name="17" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">custom</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::SHIPPING_METHOD</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getShippingMethod</item>
            </item>
            <item name="18" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">custom</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::PRODUCT_GRID</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getProductGrid</item>
            </item>
            <item name="19" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">custom</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::STORE_PHONE</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getStorePhone</item>
            </item>
            <item name="20" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">custom</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::HAS_SHIPPING_INFO</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">hasShippingInfo</item>
            </item>
            
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

I would like to add in this another argument like

```
<item name="21" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">custom</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::QUOTE_REMARKS</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getComments</item>
            </item>
```

I was able to ovveride the Model (with preferences in my own custom module di.xml), but how should I edit the original parameters ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Define the virtualType type of PdfInformation Class like below and try it:

```
<virtualType name="your_custom_name" type="Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Pdf\PdfInformation">
        <arguments>
           <argument name="variables" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="21" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">custom</item>
                    <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::QUOTE_REMARKS</item>
                    <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getComments</item>
                 </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

And try also this link as reference : https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/blockwithcustomlogger/src/master/

Answer (score 0):

You should use type to inject a new argument item to Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Pdf\PdfInformation instead of overriding the Model by preference.

Assume your vendor name is Paul, module name is AmastyRequestQuote. Let's create app/code/Paul/AmastyRequestQuote/etc/di.xml file:

```
<type name="Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Pdf\PdfInformation">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="variables" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="21" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">custom</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::QUOTE_REMARKS</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getComments</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

And don't forget to config your module depends on the Amasty_RequestQuote module:

app/code/Amasty/RequestQuote/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Paul_AmastyRequestQuote">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Amasty_RequestQuote"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Remember to remove generated folder, re-compile code, and clear the `full_page` cache type:

```
rm -rf generated
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento cache:clean full_page
```

Comment: When I do that, I cannot compil the code, it says "Constant name is expected."

Comment: I think `\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::QUOTE_REMARKS` does not exist. Please check, if it does not exist, declare this constant in your override `PdfVariables` class, and replace it with the constant in your override model. If the issues persist, please paste the error log in your question, I'll take a look.

Comment: I made a much more descriptive post to explain what it does

Comment: You have to copy completely `getComments` method from Amasty Pdfinformation` to your override class. Then remove `generated` folder and re compile code

Comment: GetComments does NOT exist in the Amasty's PdfInformation. Thats why I created this function to my own PdfInformation override

Comment: Ok, you didn't assign value to `$this->quote`, so it is null. Do you know how to inject Quote to assign Quote to `$this->quote`? If not following the Amasty module to do that. If you still can't do that, please paste the full content of `PdfInformation` from Amasty module, I'll help

Comment: The fact is that even if I look to the Amasty module, I just do not understand how the instance of the object quote is called, but as my edits works perfectly when I directly change the vendor's module, i suppose it's called ! ^^  Thanks @Tu Van , I immediately show the full content of PdfInformation (another  reply)

Comment: I've updated the answer with new code based on your new update, please give it a try.

Comment: Same result. I had to change the "private" function getComments() to "public" because if not, I get an error. Then, I tested again, i get one more time this error : Error: Call to a member function getRemarks() on null in /var/www/paul/app/code/Paul/RequestQuote/Model/Pdf/PdfInformation.php:53 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/paul/vendor/amasty/module-request-quote/Model/Pdf/PdfInformation.php(115): Paul\RequestQuote\Model\Pdf\PdfInformation->getComments() #1 /var/www/paul/vendor/amasty/module-request-quote/Model/Pdf/PdfInformation.php(106):

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140231/discussion-between-tu-van-and-paul-antoine-van-gansbeke).

Comment: I've updated the content for app/code/Paul/RequestQuote/Model/Pdf/PdfInformation.php in my answer, please update it and remove generated folder, re-compile code, clear the full_page cache type.

Comment: Hi Paul, as your issue is resolved, please mark my answer as accepted due to it works as expected. That indicates your issue is solved and helps others with the same issue find out the verified answer easily.

Answer (score 0):

Ill try to be a bit more descriptive.

What I try is to override some third party module; I succeed to do what I want, if I edit directly the vendor's files.

This is the vendor's edited di.xml file (see at the end)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 
...


<type name="Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Pdf\PdfInformation">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="variables" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">quote</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::USERNAME</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getCustomerName</item>
            </item>
            <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">custom</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::CUSTOMER_STREET</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getBillingStreet</item>
            </item>
            <item name="2" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">billing</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::CUSTOMER_CITY</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getCity</item>
            </item>
            <item name="3" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">custom</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::CUSTOMER_REGION</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getBillingRegion</item>
            </item>
            <item name="4" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">billing</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::CUSTOMER_POSTCODE</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getPostcode</item>
            </item>
            <item name="5" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">custom</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::CUSTOMER_COUNTRY</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getBillingCountryName</item>
            </item>
            <item name="6" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">billing</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::CUSTOMER_TELEPHONE</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getTelephone</item>
            </item>
            <item name="7" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">quote</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::QUOTE_NUMBER</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getIncrementId</item>
            </item>
            <item name="8" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">quote</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::QUOTE_STATUS</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getStatusLabel</item>
            </item>
            <item name="9" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">quote</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::QUOTE_DATE</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getCreatedAt</item>
            </item>
            <item name="10" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">quote</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::QUOTE_EXPIRY_DATE</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getExpiredDate</item>
            </item>
            <item name="11" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">custom</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::SHIPPING_STREET</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getShippingStreet</item>
            </item>
            <item name="12" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">shipping</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::SHIPPING_CITY</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getCity</item>
            </item>
            <item name="13" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">custom</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::SHIPPING_REGION</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getShippingRegion</item>
            </item>
            <item name="14" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">shipping</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::SHIPPING_POSTCODE</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getPostcode</item>
            </item>
            <item name="15" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">custom</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::SHIPPING_COUNTRY</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getShippingCountryName</item>
            </item>
            <item name="16" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">custom</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::SHIPPING_TELEPHONE</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getTelephone</item>
            </item>
            <item name="17" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">custom</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::SHIPPING_METHOD</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getShippingMethod</item>
            </item>
            <item name="18" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">custom</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::PRODUCT_GRID</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getProductGrid</item>
            </item>
            <item name="19" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">custom</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::STORE_PHONE</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getStorePhone</item>
            </item>
            <item name="20" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">custom</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::HAS_SHIPPING_INFO</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">hasShippingInfo</item>
            </item>
            <item name="21" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">custom</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::QUOTE_REMARKS</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getComments</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

...

I just added the last argument :

```
<item name="21" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">custom</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::QUOTE_REMARKS</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getComments</item>
            </item>
```

This is the edited Amasty/RequestQuote/Model/Pdf/PdfInformation.php

```
class PdfInformation { 
private $quote;
private $variables;
private $billing;
private $shipping;
private $dataObjectFactory;
private $countryInformationAcquirer;
private $status;
private $productGrid;
private $addressRepository;
private $registry;
private $scopeConfig;

public function __construct(
    DataObjectFactory $dataObjectFactory,
    CountryInformationAcquirerInterface $countryInformationAcquirer,
    Status $status,
    Items $productGrid,
    AddressRepository $addressRepository,
    Registry $registry,
    ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    array $variables = []
) {
    $this->variables = $variables;
    $this->dataObjectFactory = $dataObjectFactory;
    $this->countryInformationAcquirer = $countryInformationAcquirer;
    $this->status = $status;
    $this->productGrid = $productGrid;
    $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
    $this->registry = $registry;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
}
```

Where I just added the following function :

```
private function getComments(): string
{
    $json = $this->quote->getRemarks();
    if ($json != ""){
        $object = json_decode($json);
        foreach($object as $key=>$value){
            $result = $key." : ".$value."<br />";
        }
    }
    else {
        $result = "";
    }

    return (string)$result;
}
```

And finally, I edited the file Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables to add the constant REMARKS, so it becomes

```
class PdfVariables implements OptionSourceInterface {
```

public const USERNAME = 'username';
public const CUSTOMER_STREET = 'customer_street';
public const CUSTOMER_CITY = 'customer_city';
public const CUSTOMER_REGION = 'customer_region';
public const CUSTOMER_POSTCODE = 'customer_postcode';
public const CUSTOMER_COUNTRY = 'customer_country';
public const CUSTOMER_TELEPHONE = 'customer_telephone';
public const QUOTE_NUMBER = 'quote_number';
public const QUOTE_STATUS = 'quote_status';
public const QUOTE_DATE = 'quote_date';
public const QUOTE_EXPIRY_DATE = 'quote_expiry_date';
public const HAS_SHIPPING_INFO = 'has_shipping_info';
public const SHIPPING_STREET = 'shipping_street';
public const SHIPPING_CITY = 'shipping_city';
public const SHIPPING_REGION = 'shipping_region';
public const SHIPPING_POSTCODE = 'shipping_postcode';
public const SHIPPING_COUNTRY = 'shipping_country';
public const SHIPPING_TELEPHONE = 'shipping_telephone';
public const SHIPPING_METHOD = 'shipping_method';
public const PRODUCT_GRID = 'product_grid';
public const STORE_PHONE = 'store_phone';
public const QUOTE_REMARKS = 'quote_remarks';

```
/**
 * @return array|array[]
 */
public function toOptionArray()
{
    return [
        [
            'value' => self::USERNAME,
            'label' => __('Username')
        ],
        [
            'value' => self::CUSTOMER_STREET,
            'label' => __('Customer Street')
        ],
        [
            'value' => self::CUSTOMER_REGION,
            'label' => __('Customer Region')
        ],
        [
            'value' => self::CUSTOMER_POSTCODE,
            'label' => __('Customer Postcode')
        ],
        [
            'value' => self::CUSTOMER_COUNTRY,
            'label' => __('Customer Country')
        ],
        [
            'value' => self::CUSTOMER_TELEPHONE,
            'label' => __('Customer Telephone')
        ],
        [
            'value' => self::QUOTE_NUMBER,
            'label' => __('Quote Number')
        ],
        [
            'value' => self::QUOTE_STATUS,
            'label' => __('Quote Status')
        ],
        [
            'value' => self::QUOTE_DATE,
            'label' => __('Quote Date')
        ],
        [
            'value' => self::QUOTE_EXPIRY_DATE,
            'label' => __('Quote Expiry Date')
        ],
        [
            'value' => self::HAS_SHIPPING_INFO,
            'label' => __('Has Shipping Info')
        ],
        [
            'value' => self::SHIPPING_STREET,
            'label' => __('Shipping Street')
        ],
        [
            'value' => self::SHIPPING_CITY,
            'label' => __('Shipping City')
        ],
        [
            'value' => self::SHIPPING_REGION,
            'label' => __('Shipping Region')
        ],
        [
            'value' => self::SHIPPING_POSTCODE,
            'label' => __('Shipping Postcode')
        ],
        [
            'value' => self::SHIPPING_COUNTRY,
            'label' => __('Shipping Country')
        ],
        [
            'value' => self::SHIPPING_TELEPHONE,
            'label' => __('Shipping Telephone')
        ],
        [
            'value' => self::SHIPPING_METHOD,
            'label' => __('Shipping Method')
        ],
        [
            'value' => self::PRODUCT_GRID,
            'label' => __('Product Grid')
        ],
        [
            'value' => self::STORE_PHONE,
            'label' => __('Store Phone')
        ],
        [
            'value' => self::QUOTE_REMARKS,
            'label' => __('Quote Remarks')
        ],
    ];
}
```

}

My question is : how to implement this with a custopm module without editing the vendor ?

These are my files into my own module Paul/RequestQuote/

my di.xml in Paul/RequestQuote/etc/

```
<preference for="Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Pdf\PdfInformation"
            type="Paul\RequestQuote\Model\Pdf\PdfInformation" />

<preference for="Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables"
            type="Paul\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables" />

<type name="Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Pdf\PdfInformation">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="variables" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="21" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="objectType" xsi:type="string">custom</item>
                <item name="variable" xsi:type="const">\Paul\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables::QUOTE_REMARKS</item>
                <item name="method" xsi:type="string">getComments</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

This is my new Paul/RequestQuote/Model/Pdf/PdfInformation.php

```
namespace Paul\RequestQuote\Model\Pdf;
use Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Quote;
class PdfInformation extends \Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Pdf\PdfInformation {
private $quote; 

private function getComments(): string
```

{
$json = $this->quote->getRemarks();
if ($json != ""){
$object = json_decode($json);
foreach($object as $key=>$value){
$result = $key." : ".$value."
";
}
}
else {
$result = "";
}

```
return (string)$result;
```

}

And finally,; for my new Class PdfVariables, I created a Paul/RequestQuote/Model/Source/Pdfvariables and added the constant like :

```
namespace Paul\RequestQuote\Model\Source;
use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;
class PdfVariables extends \Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\PdfVariables
{ ... and I add the constant and edited fuction
```

It does not work.
I get the following error :

Firstly, the errors says that I'm trying to call a private function (getComments() in my overrided Pdfinformation class) from the amasty PdfInformation file.

Then I did change the "private" function getComments to "public"...but in that case the object "quote" is empty (it doesnt inherit from the original $this->quote

I got this error :

```
Error: Call to a member function getRemarks() on null in /var/www/site/app/code/Paul/RequestQuote/Model/Pdf/PdfInformation.php:20 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/site/vendor/amasty/module-request-quote/Model/Pdf/PdfInformation.php(115): Paul\RequestQuote\Model\Pdf\PdfInformation->getComments() #1 /var/www/site/vendor/amasty/module-request-quote/Model/Pdf/PdfInformation.php(106): Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Pdf\PdfInformation->g ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer Tu Van, This is the full PdfInformation.php Vendor's file

```
    <?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Pdf;

use Amasty\RequestQuote\Block\Pdf\Items;

use Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Quote;

use Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Registry;

use Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\RegistryConstants;

use Amasty\RequestQuote\Model\Source\Status;

use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\AddressRepository;

use Magento\Directory\Api\CountryInformationAcquirerInterface;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

use Magento\Framework\DataObjectFactory;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address;

use Magento\Store\Model\Information;

class PdfInformation
{

    /**
     * @var Quote
     */

    private $quote;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $variables;

    /**
     * @var Address
     */
    private $billing;

    /**
     * @var Address
     */
    private $shipping;

    /**
     * @var DataObjectFactory
     */
    private $dataObjectFactory;

    /**
     * @var CountryInformationAcquirerInterface
     */
    private $countryInformationAcquirer;

    /**
     * @var Status
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @var Items
     */
    private $productGrid;

    /**
     * @var AddressRepository
     */
    private $addressRepository;

    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    private $registry;

    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    private $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        DataObjectFactory $dataObjectFactory,
        CountryInformationAcquirerInterface $countryInformationAcquirer,
        Status $status,
        Items $productGrid,
        AddressRepository $addressRepository,
        Registry $registry,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        array $variables = []
    ) {
        $this->variables = $variables;
        $this->dataObjectFactory = $dataObjectFactory;
        $this->countryInformationAcquirer = $countryInformationAcquirer;
        $this->status = $status;
        $this->productGrid = $productGrid;
        $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function getQuoteDataForPdf(): array
    {
        $data = [];
        $this->quote = $this->registry->registry(RegistryConstants::AMASTY_QUOTE);
        $this->getCustomerInfo($data);

        return $data;
    }

    private function getCustomerInfo(array &$data): void
    {
        foreach ($this->variables as $variableData) {
            $object = $this->getObjectWithData($variableData['objectType']);
            $data[$variableData['variable']] = (string) $object->{$variableData['method']}();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param string $objectType
     * @return PdfInformation|Quote|\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface|\Magento\Framework\DataObject|Address
     */
    private function getObjectWithData(string $objectType)
    {
        switch ($objectType) {
            case 'quote':
                $result = $this->quote;
                break;
            case 'billing':
                $result = $this->getDefaultBilling();
                break;
            case 'shipping':
                $result = $this->getDefaultShipping();
                break;
            default:
                $result = $this;
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface|\Magento\Framework\DataObject|Address
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    private function getDefaultBilling()
    {
        if (!$this->billing) {
            $this->billing = $this->quote->getBillingAddress();
            if (!$this->billing->getId()) {
                $this->billing = $this->quote->getCustomer()->getDefaultBilling();
            }
        }

        return $this->billing;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address|\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    private function getDefaultShipping()
    {
        if (!$this->shipping) {
            $this->shipping = $this->quote->getShippingAddress();
            if (!$this->shipping->getId()) {
                $this->shipping = $this->quote->getCustomer()->getDefaultShipping();
            }
        }

        return $this->shipping;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     * @return \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface|\Magento\Framework\DataObject
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    private function getAddressById(int $id)
    {
        try {
            $address = $this->addressRepository->getById($id);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            $address = $this->dataObjectFactory->create();
        }

        return $address;
    }

    private function getBillingCountryName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->prepareCountryName($this->getDefaultBilling());
    }

    private function getShippingCountryName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->prepareCountryName($this->getDefaultShipping());
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface|\Magento\Framework\DataObject|Address $address
     * @return string
     */
    private function prepareCountryName($address): string
    {
        $countryName = '';
        $countryId = $address->getCountryId();

        if ($countryId) {
            $countryInformation = $this->countryInformationAcquirer->getCountryInfo($countryId);
            $countryName = $countryInformation->getFullNameLocale();
        }

        return $countryName;
    }

    private function getBillingStreet(): ?string
    {
        return $this->prepareStreet($this->getDefaultBilling());
    }

    private function getShippingStreet(): ?string
    {
        return $this->prepareStreet($this->getDefaultShipping());
    }

    private function getTelephone(): ?string
    {
        $telephone = $this->getDefaultShipping()->getTelephone();
        if ($telephone) {
            //phpcs:ignore
            return '<span>' . __('T') . '</span>' . $telephone;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private function hasShippingInfo(): bool
    {
        return $this->getShippingStreet()
            || $this->getShippingRegion()
            || $this->getShippingCountryName()
            || $this->getDefaultShipping()->getCity()
            || $this->getDefaultShipping()->getPostcode()
            || $this->getTelephone();
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface|\Magento\Framework\DataObject|Address $address
     * @return string|null
     */
    private function prepareStreet($address): ?string
    {
        $street = $address->getStreet();

        return is_array($street) ? implode(',', $street) : $street;
    }

    private function getProductGrid(): ?string
    {
        return $this->productGrid->setQuote($this->quote)->toHtml();
    }

    private function getShippingMethod(): ?string
    {
        return $this->quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingDescription();
    }

    private function getBillingRegion(): string
    {
        return $this->getRegion($this->getDefaultBilling()->getRegion());
    }

    private function getShippingRegion(): string
    {
        return $this->getRegion($this->getDefaultShipping()->getRegion());
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\RegionInterface|string $region
     * @return string
     */
    private function getRegion($region): string
    {
        $result = '';
        if ($region) {
            $result = is_string($region) ? $region : $region->getRegion();
        }

        return (string)$result;
    }

    private function getStorePhone(): string
    {
        $storeId = (int)$this->quote->getStoreId();
        $configValue = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            Information::XML_PATH_STORE_INFO_PHONE,
            'store',
            $storeId
        );
        return $configValue ?: '';
    }
}
```